# AJAX function calling on success

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, ajax

My javascript code -

```
function updateWhatIfPrivacyLevelRemove(recordId, correspondingDetailIDs) {
    var ajaxCall = $.ajax({ data: { Svc: cntnrRoot,
        Cmd: 'updateWhatIfPrivacyLevel',
        updatePrivacyAction: 'Remove',
        recordID: recordID
        },
        dataType: "text",
        context: this,
        cache: false
    });

    $.when(ajaxCall).then(updateWhatIfPrivacyLevelRemoveSuccess(recordID, correspondingResidentDetailIDs));
}

function updateWhatIfPrivacyLevelRemoveSuccess(recordID, correspondingResidentDetailIDs) {
    //several other lines of non-related code
            $.ajax({ data: { Svc: cntnrRoot,
                Cmd: 'handleResidentRow',
                recordID: 1,
                active: 0
            },
                dataType: "text",
                context: this,
                cache: false
            });
}
```

within my C# code I handle the call backs for 'updateWhatIfPrivacyLevel' and 'handleResidentRow'. I can tell that the AJAX callback to handleResidnetRow is called before updateWhatIfPrivacyLevel.

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're trying to set up the callback, you're actually **calling** the function. In other words, you're not passing that "updateWhatIf..." function as the callback, you're passing in its return value (which looks like it'd always be `undefined`).

Try this instead:

```
$.when(ajaxCall).then(function() {
  updateWhatIfPrivacyLevelRemoveSuccess(recordID, correspondingResidentDetailIDs);
});
```

A reference to a function name is a reference to the function as object, and can be used to pass the function as a callback. However, a reference to a function followed by `( )` is a **call** to the function, which will be evaluated so that the return value can be used in the context of the surrounding expression. Thus, in your code, you pass `undefined` (the result of the function call) to the `.then()` method, which of course won't do what you want.

It's important to keep in mind that jQuery is just JavaScript, and in particular a JavaScript function library. Though the `.then()` thing *looks* like a language construct, it isn't — the JavaScript interpreter doesn't treat it specially in any way.

An alternative to using an anonymous function as in my suggestion is to use the `.bind()` method on the Function prototype in newer browsers. That basically does the same thing for you, but it's stylistically more like traditional functional programming.